# SQL web Reporting from multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Firstly let me start by letting you know that I am new to SQL reports. What I have is 2 independent customers, each have the same database structure, just on different SQL database machines.

What I want to do is create a reporting suite and have the customers use this so that they can run the reports from there own databases.

How is it best to do this

Thanks you in advance

Alpesh

Comment: Who hosts the DBs? Who will be hosting the reports?

Comment: I will be hosting it

Answer (score 2):

You can serve reports via SSRS from a central server.
For each user you can use different data sources behind like two different report folders containing same rdl's but data source object mapping to own data

Comment: SSRS uses Windows security for object access, so you will want to make sure each company has Windows userid's and limit access to each others folders. The Datasources could go off of hard coded SQL server logins, and point to the right place i.e. DataSourceA , DatasourceB. Then have the actual reports in seperate folders as well, easier for managing security and customizations which might differ between companies.

Comment: Thanks a lot.ill have a look into this and see how it goes